# Sending SQL string in for every calculated date

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I have a sql string now, and I need to send it in, for every day between 2 dates. like, if the first date yould be, 01.01.0001 and the last date would be 03.01.0001 then, the string should be send 3 times in with every date (01. + 02. + 03.01.0001)

Any ideas for I can integrate that in my script when I already need to send the string in for every selected member ID?

That means, if I have 3 IDs, and 3 days, there would be 3 strings for every ID = 9 strings per total.

Please note, that the dates are dynamic as well as the amout of IDs.

For now, I have:

```
foreach (DataRow row in m_dt.Rows) {
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray) {
                string sqlString = "INSERT INTO [table] ([id] ,[day] ,[month] ,[year]) VALUES('" + item + "', '" + reason + "', '10', '08', '2016', '1' )";
                Sendin( sqlString );
            }
```

Comment: downvoted + deleted php, mysql tags because this clearly isn't PHP code and that isn't mysql

Comment: Thanks for keeping in mind that I can't use another tags. Appreciated.

Comment: Your insert statement does not make sense. You have 4 insert columns, but 6 values to insert. Please provide a valid SQL. It would be good if you would send code that at least runs without basic SQL errors.

Comment: I just deleted them. I need ID DAY MONTH YEAR, That's all. Ignore the values.